# Existence of a conditional distribution

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ and $Y$ be standard Borel spaces and let $J$ be an analytic subset of $X\times \mathcal P(Y)$ where $\mathcal P(\Omega)$  is a set of probability measures on a Borel space $\Omega$ endowed with the topology of weak convergence. By $\mathcal B(\Omega)$ I denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Omega$.

Consider $P\in \mathcal P(X\times Y)$ and let $(A_k)_{k\in \Bbb N}\subset \mathcal B(X)$ be a generator of $\mathcal B(X)$. Suppose that for any $k\in \Bbb N$ there exists a universally measurable kernel $q_k:X\to \mathcal P(Y)$ such that $(x,q(x))\in J$ for all $x\in X$ and such that
$$
  P(A_k\times B) = \int_{A_k}q_k(B|x)P_X(\mathrm dx) \qquad \forall B\in \mathcal B(Y),
$$
where $P_X$ is a marginal of $P$ on $X$. How can I show that there exists a universally measurable kernel $q:X\to \mathcal P(Y)$ such that $(x,q(x))\in J$ for all $x\in X$ and such that
$$
  P(A\times B) = \int_A q(B|x)P_X(\mathrm dx),\qquad \forall A\in \mathcal B(X),B\in \mathcal B(Y),
$$
that is $q$ is a conditional distribution of $P$ whose graph is a subset of $J$?